# Submitting form via Selenium just takes back to the original page

Tags: python, forms, selenium, python-3.x, webautomation

I am trying to login into a website using Selenium. The website is http://projecteuler.net/login.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get('http://projecteuler.net/login')
username = browser.find_element_by_id('username')
username.send_keys(USERNAME_HERE)
password = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys(PASSWORD_HERE)

browser.find_element_by_name("login").submit()
```

The program is working correctly upto the last statement. I tried omitting the last statement and manually logged in and it worked.  But when I added the last statement and ran the program it just seemed to reload the same page minus the information that I had placed via the program.

So it is only the submission that is giving problem. I viewed the source and confirmed whether there is some other element by that name but there was no other element by name "login". So what am I getting wrong here? Do I need to take care of something else also?

There is a weird thing happening. When I have done form submission via code and try to view the source in Google Chrome  33.0.1750.154 m I am getting the below.
[image]

Comment: Try `click()` instead of `submit()`

Comment: @Amey This worked. But as per http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html `submit()` should also work or did I miss read something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `click()` instead of `submit()`

```
Submit is particularly useful for forms without submit buttons, e.g. single-input “Search” forms.
```

Source:-
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/selenium/selenium.selenium.html?highlight=submit#selenium.selenium.selenium.submit

In your case there is a submit button, better to just click it.